# pathauto_clean_string and accents from a bootstrap PHP file

Tags: 7, bootstrapping, transliteration

I have a single PHP file which makes a bootstrap of Drupal 7. The code is below. When I try to use pathauto_clean_string in a spanish string with accents (á é ... , etc.) it deletes the character instead of removing the accent using transliteration module (also affects other special chars, obviously). I have included also this module in the bootstrap but cannot have the PHP script to behave exactly as the Drupal site, which is doing properly the transliteration in file names and also from my own custom module.

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT','/home/example.com/public_html');
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/all/modules/transliteration/transliteration.inc'; 
 require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/all/modules/pathauto/pathauto.inc';

drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

if(isset($_GET['string'])) echo pathauto_cleanstring(urldecode($_GET['string']));
```

Result with www.example.com?string=está-cañón : est-can

Result with the same string and module, same function and correct, expected, result: esta-canon

Comment: Your code works properly for me; can you replicate this issue in local development environment?

Comment: Working in XAMPP under Windows XP. Apparently same config. In remote (Linux) not working, in PHP file (code above), working under "full Drupal" environment (code inside module). Now is where I cannot understand a thing.

Comment: Strange; it's probably something in PHP configuration. Did you try removing `urldecode()`?

Comment: Yes, I tried even "illogical" urlencode. Also injecting the string directly in a variable. I see that transliteration is not necessary after all, maybe pathauto loads it when is needed. I am using PHP 5.5x in server and changed it recently, but it is strange that it does not affect the module. I will try to debug it to low level stage to see what are the input - output of the function and where is the change.

Comment: Here's just an idea: what about the encoding of your PHP script? Try resaving it to UTF-8, I've see all sorts of weird things when this is not the case for whatever reason.

Comment: Yes, I revised it. I changed from utf-8 w/o bom to just utf-8 as you say, even ANSI, and still does not work. Also included header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); variable_set('language_default', "es"); It must be the simplest thing but cannot locate it.

Answer (score 0):

After having a look at the code from the [pathauto_cleanstring](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/pathauto/pathauto.inc/function/pathauto_cleanstring/7) function, I would suggest testing the following:

1. Checking the value of pathauto_transliterate prior to calling the pathauto_cleanstring function

   variable_get('pathauto_transliterate', FALSE)
2. If that value is FALSE, you probably found the reason. Try setting that variable to TRUE to force use of transliteration inside the pathauto_cleanstring function. N.B.: You only need to set this value once.

   variable_set('pathauto_transliterate', TRUE), or
   drush vset pathauto_transliterate TRUE
3. Try your code again. Fingers crossed!

I suspect that your code never actually uses the transliterate function, but that is something that you can check by dumping the 'pathauto_transliterate' variable in the various scenarios where your code is executed (in-module, custom script, etc.)

Comment: It throws a 500 internal server error. In any case, in the module the working is right, and I would not set a variable that is not multi-user, because it is completely global to the site, so don't think it is a good recommendation to change the value of something that should not change - it is set in the admin frontend.

Comment: The first thing you need to check, without changing the value of the variable, is if you get the same value for that variable, inside and outside of the module setting. If you don't that can explain the mystery you are facing. What is the value of that variable at the moment?

Comment: After clearing out some things, the variable when I make the get method call is 1, true. The reason of the behaviour is other. Maybe it will be an enduring mystery for the next generations.